# Classifying multiple features

Tags: matlab, classification, svm

I have a problem and I need help...

I am working on image recognition.

I want to train a classifier, for a couple of features:

**F1.** HoG features
**F2.** Color features
**F3.** Aspect ratio
**F4.** Area, Mean and Kurtosis.

So I have:

```
 training=imageSet(imgFolder1, 'recursive')

 test=imageSet(imgFolder2, 'recursive')

 Cell size=[4,4];
 hogFeatureSize=length(hog_4x4);

 for j=1:numel(training)

       numImages=training(j).count

       features=zeros(numImages, higFeatureSize, 'single')

       for k=1:numImages
       I=read(training (j), k);
   features (k, :)=extractHOGFeatures(img, 'cellsize', cellsize);

        end
  labels=repmat(training(j).Description,numImages, 1);

    TrainingFeatures=[trainingFeatures, features]
   TrainingLabels=[trainingLabels, labels]
 end

   Classifier=fitcecoc(trainingFeatures, trainingLabels]

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Now how do I include **F2**, **F3** and **F4** above features into this classifier for training?

Thank you.